# Quill.js Edit Email Template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quill

I want to edit my templates via Quill. I'm using **bubble** theme. So here is my component;

```
<template>
    <QuillEditor @input="onInputChange" theme="bubble" toolbar="essential" id="quill-Editor" @ready="ready"></QuillEditor>
</template>

<script>
import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill'
import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.bubble.css';
export default {
    props: ['value'],
    components: {
        QuillEditor
    },
    created(){
        console.log();
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.querySelector('#quill-Editor .ql-editor').innerHTML = this.value
        }, 100);
    },
    methods: {
        onInputChange() {
            this.$emit('input',  document.querySelector('#quill-Editor .ql-editor').innerHTML);  
        },
        ready(editor){
            editor.getModule('toolbar').addHandler('image', () => {
                const tooltip = editor.theme.tooltip;
                const originalSave = tooltip.save;
                const originalHide = tooltip.hide;

                tooltip.save = function () {
                    const range = editor.getSelection(true);
                    const value = this.textbox.value;
                    if (value) {
                        editor.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', value, 'user');
                    }
                };
                tooltip.hide = function () {
                    tooltip.save = originalSave;
                    tooltip.hide = originalHide;
                    tooltip.hide();
                };
                tooltip.edit('image');
                tooltip.textbox.placeholder = 'Embed URL';
            });
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Value is [this](https://codepen.io/havenotfear/pen/MWQrxab) html value. But when I do that quill is deleting all tags giving just few blank `<p>` tag. What should I do? How can I do that?

Comment: You should use `v-model` instead of `innerHTML` - as explained in https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor#component

Comment: @IVOGELOV its not working too.

Comment: It works just fine - https://jsfiddle.net/Lwkbje7v/